# What do experimental philosophers say about nihilism?

Tags: nihilism, experimental-philosophy

What do [experimental](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/experimental-moral/) philosophers say about nihilism? Has anyone studied the beliefs and judgments of nihilists, either self defined or just obviously so, in order to shed light on the problems of nihilism, especially what those problems are?

> Experimental philosophy is an emerging field of philosophical inquiry
> that makes use of empirical data—often gathered through surveys which
> probe the intuitions of ordinary people—in order to inform research on
> philosophical questions

By 'nihilism' I meann "the meta-ethical view that nothing is morally right or morally wrong". By 'problem' I mean questions that moral nihilists pose as philosophers, and how they may be illuminated rather than necessarily answered with experimental philosophy.

Comment: Which philosophers do you consider "experimental philosophers" and why?

Comment: what an odd question @JoWehler can you explain what you mean?

Comment: i like you jo, but i think there has to be some kinda continuity in how people comment @JoWehler so i'm somewhat interested in what you mean by "why" and so will add a 'what?'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because based on the comments of the user I am in doubt that the user is a real person.

Comment: Nietzsche also had not....up to some point in time! (I just want to warn/prevent, it is good that you don't have one (or more)!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it's extremely hard for me to tell what has confused you @Community can you pleased add a note saying what you found "unclear"? do you need me to define "nihilist" "experimental philosophy" "belief" "judgment" or are you just a troll?

Comment: I think people have lost faith in nihilism.

Comment: how would anyone notice @ScottRowe ?

Comment: not a nhilist again @ScottRowe not becasue it's a meaningless phrase or belief etc., as some things do seem to be moral, not becasuse it's inconsistent, but i feel that it's an an absurd an illusion in life as any other is (which is inconsistent with "why" i embraced nihilism for the day)